# Median of two variables/columns

Tags: variables, multiple-columns, spss, median

I know that you can get Medians of two variables or columns easily in other programs, but is this possible in SPSS? So for example I have

measurement1 measurement2 
1                    2
1                      2
1                     1
2                     3
5                     4

and I want the median for all of these together? So my answer should be 2.

Comment: You will have to stack them into the same column using `VARSTOCASES`. After that options you can use are `FREQUENCIES` or `AGGREGATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Andy W says, this will do the job:

```
*creating sample data.
DATA LIST list/measurement1 measurement2 .
begin data
1         2
1         2
1         1
2         3
5         4
end data.

* data restructure.
dataset name OrigData.
dataset copy Long.
dataset activate Long.
VARSTOCASES /make val from measurement1 measurement2/index=Measurment(val).

* now you can get your answer in the output window.
frequencies ‎‪val/STATISTICS=median.

* or in a separate dataset.
DATASET DECLARE YourAnswer.
AGGREGATE  /OUTFILE='YourAnswer'  /BREAK=  /val_median=MEDIAN(val).
dataset activate YourAnswer.
```

Comment: In line "dataset name OrigData" a dot is missing ;-)

Comment: Indeed... thanks for the correction @mirirai - added an edit.